# Shopify/Liquid: Buy Now vs Sold Out : Sold Out Buttons stacking under one product when using elsif code Buy Now are showing properly

Tags: for-loop, if-statement, shopify, liquid

I have been bashing my head against this code all day. I've managed to get it to work almost perfectly, but the "Sold Out" buttons are stacking under one product instead of showing under each of the two products which are sold out.

Use case: Gift with Product promotion. I have used weight as a selector to work with only one variant per product as this gift with purchase offer is only valid with certain product sizes. While I have written the code to completely remove the product once it is sold out, I would prefer to have a "sold out" button show up when a specific variant is out of stock. Note: different sizes of the product may still be in stock, but the one associated with the gift with purchase is sold out and therefore I would like to have a "sold out" button come up.

I am including the code as well as an image of the section as it is currently rendering so you can see what is happening.

The code I have added is at the bottom of the file. I assume my for loop isn't correctly structured but I can't figure out what I got wrong. Thanks in advance for taking a look!

[Image of Gift with Purchase section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZS08n.jpg)

```html
{% comment %}
    Renders a product card

    Accepts:
    - product_card_product: {Object} Product Liquid object (optional)
    - media_size: {String} Size of the product image card. Values are "square" and "portrait". Default is "square" (optional)
    - show_secondary_image: {Boolean} Show the secondary image on hover. Default: false (optional)
    - add_image_padding: {Boolean} Enables padding on the image to space out the grid
    - show_vendor: {Boolean} Show the product vendor. Default: false
    - show_image_outline: {Boolean} Show card outline. Default: true (optional)
    - show_rating: {Boolean} Show the product rating. Default: false

    Usage:
    {% render 'product-card-gwp', show_vendor: section.settings.show_vendor %}
{% endcomment %}

{{ 'component-rating.css' | asset_url | stylesheet_tag }}

  
<div class="card-wrapper">  
  <div class="card-information">
    <div class="card-information__wrapper">
      {%- if show_vendor -%}
        <span class="visually-hidden">{{ 'accessibility.vendor' | t }}</span>
        <div class="caption-with-letter-spacing light">{{ product_card_product.vendor }}</div>
      {%- endif -%}

      {%- if product_card_product.featured_media -%}
        <h3 class="card-information__text h5">
          <a href="{{ product_card_product.url | default: '#' }}" class="full-unstyled-link">
            {{ product_card_product.title | escape }}
          </a>
        </h3>
      {%- endif -%}

      {%- for variant in product_card_product.variants -%}
      {% assign theweight = variant.weight | weight_with_unit: variant.weight_unit %}
      {%- if theweight == '9 g' and variant.inventory_quantity != 0 -%}       
      
      {% render 'price', product: product_card_product, use_variant: product_card_product.first_available_variant.id, price_class: price--large -%} 
           <div class="caption-with-letter-spacing light"> FREE SHIPPING </div>
           <div class="caption-with-letter-spacing light">   </div>

      {% continue %}
      {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
  </div>     
    
  <div class="card card--product{% if product_card_product.featured_media == nil %} card--text-only card--soft{% endif %}{% if product_card_product.featured_media != nil and show_image_outline %} card--outline{% endif %}" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="card__inner">
      {%- if product_card_product.featured_media -%}
        {%- liquid
          assign featured_media_aspect_ratio = product_card_product.featured_media.aspect_ratio

          if product_card_product.featured_media.aspect_ratio == nil
            assign featured_media_aspect_ratio = 1
          endif
        -%}

        <div{% if add_image_padding %} class="card__media-full-spacer"{% endif %}>
          <div class="media media--transparent media--{{ media_size }} media--hover-effect"
            {% if media_size == 'adapt' and product_card_product.featured_media %} style="padding-bottom: {{ 1 | divided_by: featured_media_aspect_ratio | times: 100 }}%;"{% endif %}
          >
            <img
              srcset="{%- if product_card_product.featured_media.width >= 165 -%}{{ product_card_product.featured_media | img_url: '165x' }} 165w,{%- endif -%}
                {%- if product_card_product.featured_media.width >= 360 -%}{{ product_card_product.featured_media | img_url: '360x' }} 360w,{%- endif -%}
                {%- if product_card_product.featured_media.width >= 533 -%}{{ product_card_product.featured_media | img_url: '533x' }} 533w,{%- endif -%}
                {%- if product_card_product.featured_media.width >= 720 -%}{{ product_card_product.featured_media | img_url: '720x' }} 720w,{%- endif -%}
                {%- if product_card_product.featured_media.width >= 940 -%}{{ product_card_product.featured_media | img_url: '940x' }} 940w,{%- endif -%}
                {%- if product_card_product.featured_media.width >= 1066 -%}{{ product_card_product.featured_media | img_url: '1066x' }} 1066w,{%- endif -%}
                {{ product_card_product.featured_media | img_url: 'master' }} {{ product_card_product.featured_media.width }}w"
              src="{{ product_card_product.featured_media | img_url: '533x' }}"
              sizes="(min-width: {{ settings.page_width }}px) {{ settings.page_width | minus: 130 | divided_by: 4 }}px, (min-width: 990px) calc((100vw - 130px) / 4), (min-width: 750px) calc((100vw - 120px) / 3), calc((100vw - 35px) / 2)"
              alt="{{ product_card_product.featured_media.alt | escape }}"
              loading="lazy"
              class="motion-reduce"
              width="{{ product_card_product.featured_media.width }}"
              height="{{ product_card_product.featured_media.height }}"
            >

            {%- if product_card_product.media[1] != nil and show_secondary_image -%}
              <img
                srcset="{%- if product_card_product.media[1].width >= 165 -%}{{ product_card_product.media[1] | img_url: '165x' }} 165w,{%- endif -%}
                  {%- if product_card_product.media[1].width >= 360 -%}{{ product_card_product.media[1] | img_url: '360x' }} 360w,{%- endif -%}
                  {%- if product_card_product.media[1].width >= 533 -%}{{ product_card_product.media[1] | img_url: '533x' }} 533w,{%- endif -%}
                  {%- if product_card_product.media[1].width >= 720 -%}{{ product_card_product.media[1] | img_url: '720x' }} 720w,{%- endif -%}
                  {%- if product_card_product.media[1].width >= 940 -%}{{ product_card_product.media[1] | img_url: '940x' }} 940w,{%- endif -%}
                  {%- if product_card_product.media[1].width >= 1066 -%}{{ product_card_product.media[1] | img_url: '1066x' }} 1066w,{%- endif -%}
                  {{ product_card_product.media[1] | img_url: 'master' }} {{ product_card_product.media[1].width }}w"
                src="{{ product_card_product.media[1] | img_url: '533x' }}"
                sizes="(min-width: {{ settings.page_width }}px) {{ settings.page_width | minus: 130 | divided_by: 4 }}px, (min-width: 990px) calc((100vw - 130px) / 4), (min-width: 750px) calc((100vw - 120px) / 3), calc((100vw - 35px) / 2)"
                alt="{{ product_card_product.media[1].alt | escape }}"
                loading="lazy"
                class="motion-reduce"
              width="{{ product_card_product.media[1].width }}"
              height="{{ product_card_product.media[1].height }}"
              >
            {%- endif -%}
          </div>
        </div>
      {%- else -%}
        <div class="card__content">
          <h2 class="card__text h3">
            <a href="{{ product_card_product.url | default: '#' }}" class="full-unstyled-link">
              {{ product_card_product.title }}
            </a>
          </h2>
        </div>
      {%- endif -%}

      <div class="card__badge">
        {%- if product_card_product.available == false -%}
          <span class="badge badge--bottom-left color-{{ settings.sold_out_badge_color_scheme }}">{{ 'products.product.sold_out' | t }}</span>
        {%- elsif product_card_product.compare_at_price > product_card_product.price and product_card_product.available -%}
          <span class="badge badge--bottom-left color-{{ settings.sale_badge_color_scheme }}">{{ 'products.product.on_sale' | t }}</span>
        {%- endif -%}
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

    {%- for variant in product_card_product.variants -%}
    {% assign theweight = variant.weight | weight_with_unit: variant.weight_unit %}
    {%- if theweight == '9 g' and variant.inventory_quantity != 0 -%} 

        <form method="post" action="/cart/add">

          <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ product_card_product.first_available_variant.id }}" />
          <input type="hidden" type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" value="1"/>
          <input type="submit" value="Buy Now" class="button" />

        </form>
     {% elsif theweight == '9 g' and variant.inventory_quantity == 0 %}
      
         <div class="learn-more-button">
            <span>              
              <a href="{{ product_card_product.url }}" class="button">
                SOLD OUT
              </a>
             </span>
          </div>


    {% endif %}          
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Could be a CSS problem, what's in the class .learn-more-button?

Comment: I suspect you are right! 
.learn-more-button {
  font-size: 1.7rem;
  justify-content:flex-end;
} 
I think it's the "justify-content" that is my problem. I will create a sold-out button and see. Thanks!

Comment: @FabioFilippi unfortunately that is not the issue. I created a button specific to this item and removed the flex and it changed nothing.

Comment: You should try in the Chrome developer tool to check why Buy Now buttons are in that position, and why the Sold Out button is not.

Comment: Are you sure that you do not have more "9 g" variants than one and both of them are with 0 quantity?
You are looping all of the variants and showing a button for each of them, based on the if statements.
I think that everything works as expected, so check your if statements.
Probably you are triggering the `elsif` twice and that's why you render it twice.

Comment: HI @FabioFilippi I tried inspect and came up dry - except that there is a difference in what shows above the "Sold Out" button. It shows 
.product-grid .grid__item>* {
    flex: 1;
}
6 times, which is once for each in-stock item. While the "buy now" buttons do not show that in style. That's the only significant difference that I can see. But I can't figure out why unless my loop isn't working the way I expected it to.

Comment: @Rado that makes sense, that I am triggering it twice, but I don't understand how. The code (I thought) was pretty straightforward. I tried adding {% continue %} and it made no difference. I move the "for" statement to the top of the file, but that didn't work. I'm baffled. I did check on the other item and it was not set up correctly. It is now and is showing up okay, but the Bright Crystal still has two buttons showing up. I am going to check the set up for that product and see if another variant was incorrectly set up and it causing the second button.

Comment: Try to log what the variant returns inside your elsif
<script>
  console.log({{ variant | json }});
</script>

This will give you, which two variants are those buttons for with the related data.
The whole thing is coming from the back office and the inventory.

Comment: @rado you were absolutely right, there were issues with the product set up for both of those products. Low hanging fruit and I didn't even think to check! Problem solved now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @FabioFilippi there were issues with the product set up for both of those products. Low hanging fruit and I didn't even think to check! Problem solved now. Thanks for your help!